# How to get the name of running pod instead of a terminating pod?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Hi I am having a shell script.

i am trying the following command to get a pod name

```
K6_POD=$(kubectl get pod -l 'app.kubernetes.io/component=k6' -n k6 -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
```

however with the above command,  it returns the name of a terminating pod instead of a pod with status Running
appreciate if you can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `--field-selector` flag e.g. `kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase=Running`

source: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/